# How do I use the Like Function in Excel VBA properly?

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I have 2 arrays, one with filepaths and 1 with key terms that are supposed to do things if they match the file path. I cannot get the 2 arrays to match, i'm trying to use wildcards.

```
For d = 0 To C
    If arr2(d) <> "" Then   
        For i = LBound(Arr3) To UBound(Arr3)
            If (Arr3(i) <> "") And ("*" & Arr3(i) & "*") Like ("*" & arr2(d) & "*") Then
                MsgBox arr2(d) & "----" & Arr3(i)
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

I have moved the message box to examine the terms before they enter the IF statment, which only makes me more confused.
This is the msgbox text of 3 array entries that should produce a match, surely?!

MBappform.txt----appform

selfdec.txt----selfdec

confidentiality.txt----confi

```
I've tried this with and without double ASTERISK statements, I've tried one of each with ASTERISK statements. 
I've got no idea why this isn't working.
```

Any help appreciated

EDIT:

```
For d = 0 To C
   
   If arr2(d) <> "" Then
       
    For i = LBound(Arr3) To UBound(Arr3)
    MsgBox "Do these Match?   " & arr2(d) & " = " & Arr3(i) 
    & vbCrLf & 
    (Arr3(i) Like "*" & arr2(d) & "*")
    
    If Arr3(i) Like "*" & arr2(d) & "*" Then
    MsgBox "Works"
    End If
    
    
    Next
   
   End If
   Next
```

Perhaps if I gave more context, as this still isn't working unfortunatley.
arr2(D) is an array of file names in a directory, C is the count of how many files in the directory.

For each file in arr2 i want to cross reference an array of key terms in arr3.

So for each file, this should cross reference no. 1 of arr2 with 8 of arr3, then it should cross reference no.2 of arr2 with the same 8 of arr3.

For whatever reason the strings I've listed don't seem to provide a match for example appform vs MBappform.txt doesn't provide a match.

The variables, which I agree are poorly named, aren't mixed up.

*Psuedocode would be like this...*

Loop all list 1
For active list 1 element - does it match any list 2 element

Is list 1.item1 equal to any list 2
if it is then save list 2 item for later
if not do nothing,

Once compared all the List 2 items to the first list 1 item, compare the next list 1 item (item2) to the list items

...and so on.

Comment: `For i = LBound(Arr3) To UBound(Arr3)
    If Arr3(i) <> "" Then MsgBox arr2(d) & "----" & Arr3(i)
    
    If (Arr3(i) <> "") And (Arr3(i)) Like ("*" & arr2(d) & "*") Then
    MsgBox "Works"
    End If
  `

Comment: Hey man, I've tried this just now. Removing the <> "" etc, moving asterisk still got false when its matching :(

Comment: see my answer below and the proof that this is the correct syntax.

Comment: I moved the msgbox outside of the IF again, there are at least 4 that should be matching. 
Arr3 contains ("appform, selfdec, Confi") 
Arr2 contains  ("MBappform.txt, Mbselfdec.txt, Marks Confidentiality.txt)

Comment: you mixed up `Arr2 ` and `arr3` then. Switch them and use meaningful names for your variables. Using numbered variable names like `Arr2 ` and `arr3` is the worst you can do. See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to test

```
If Arr3(i) Like "*" & Arr2(d) & "*" Then
```

It is not necessary to test `Arr3(i) <> ""` because it doesn't match `"*" & arr2(d) & "*"` anyway if it is empty.

Asterisks are only used after the `Like` operator.

You can easily test it with

```
MsgBox "MBappform.txt" Like "*" & "appform" & "*"
```

which will give you `True`.

---

edit:

looks like you mixed up your variables:

```
If Arr2(i) Like "*" & Arr3(d) & "*" Then
```

Use meaningful names for your variables. Using numbered variable names like `Arr2` and `Arr3` is the worst you can do.

---

edit 2:

Please check out the following example. With this example you should be able to fix your code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindKeywordsInFileNames()
    Dim ArrFileNames As Variant
    ArrFileNames = Array("MBappform.txt", "selfdec.txt", "confidentiality.txt", "SomeRandomFile.txt", "AnotherFile.txt")
    'instead of the above code retrieve your file names

    Dim ArrKeyWords As Variant
    ArrKeyWords = Array("appform", "selfdec", "confi")
    'the keywords you are looking for in the filenames
    
    
    Dim FileName As Variant
    For Each FileName In ArrFileNames
        Dim KeyWord As Variant
        For Each KeyWord In ArrKeyWords

            If FileName Like "*" & KeyWord & "*" Then
                'key word is in the file name
                Debug.Print FileName, KeyWord, "True"
            Else
                'key word is not in the file name
                Debug.Print FileName, KeyWord, "False"
            End If
            
        Next KeyWord
    Next FileName
End Sub
```

The output in the immediate window should be something like:

```
MBappform.txt               appform       True
MBappform.txt               selfdec       False
MBappform.txt               confi         False
selfdec.txt                 appform       False
selfdec.txt                 selfdec       True
selfdec.txt                 confi         False
confidentiality.txt         appform       False
confidentiality.txt         selfdec       False
confidentiality.txt         confi         True
SomeRandomFile.txt          appform       False
SomeRandomFile.txt          selfdec       False
SomeRandomFile.txt          confi         False
AnotherFile.txt             appform       False
AnotherFile.txt             selfdec       False
AnotherFile.txt             confi         False
```

---

edit 3

if you don't have an array of file names (as you said in the beginning of your question) then you would need another loop to use with `Dir()`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindKeywordsInFileNames()
    Dim ArrKeyWords As Variant
    ArrKeyWords = Array("appform", "selfdec", "confi")
    'the keywords you are looking for in the filenames
    
    
    Dim FileName As String 'initialize folder (and first file name)
    FileName = Dir("C:\Temp\")
    
    Do While FileName <> vbNullString
        Dim KeyWord As Variant
        For Each KeyWord In ArrKeyWords

            If FileName Like "*" & KeyWord & "*" Then
                'key word is in the file name
                Debug.Print FileName, KeyWord, "True"
            Else
                'key word is not in the file name
                Debug.Print FileName, KeyWord, "False"
            End If
            
        Next KeyWord
        
        FileName = Dir() 'next filename
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey man, still having some issues. Have edited my original question to add more details. Thank you for your help so far. FYI the array of filenames have been read in via a DIR() if that changes anything. Both arrays are declared as strings however. CHeers

Comment: @RyanPearson I added a full example. With this you should be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Oh man, i am still having major issues, this does however appear to be working - i really appreciate it! I now have further questions regarding array usage with Dir() - should i ask another question or Edit this one again to explain the problems? I'm sorry that i am so basic with this...

Comment: @RyanPearson Well check again. In your initial question you said you have an array of files. Please be more precise when asking questions. If you ask X you will get an answer for X and not for Y.